# PHP urlencode converting HTML special characters

Tags: php, html, urlencode, chars

Ive done a good deal of searching and so far can't find this already answered (though I might not be asking properly).

I have a simple title string on a page thats stored into a php variable

```
$title
```

When I print_r it I get back a happy, normal, string like I should

```
Art's of Glass: Photos From Crystal Castles' Gra
```

Now here is where Im lost. I run urlencode on this variable and I get back

```
urlencode($title);
Art%26%23039%3Bs+of+Glass%3A+Photos+From+Crystal+Castles%26%23039%3B+Gra
```

If you look at the first 10 chars, the urlencode did what it was supposed to, but it also did a little extra. It changed the "'" into it's html encoding ('), and THEN did urlencode on that resulting string.

When I print a manually encoded string

```
urlencode("Art's");
Art%27s
```

The result comes out correctly.

I can't for the life of me figure out why that extra step is happening in the first example. I've tried everything. I've htmlspecialchar_decode -d $title before encoding it, I've printed it every way possible, I've tried rawurlencode, I've tried every way of reversing the html special chars on the javascript side, but ended up nowhere. If anyone can shed some light, even some suggestions as to possible problems, that would be appreciated. I really want to avoid having to 'tailor' the solution to this particular instance as it might show up in other disguises later on.

**Solution**: Quentin and JMB helped sort this out, the original string was already HTML encoded, had to use htmlspecialchars_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES) to turn it into a normal string.

Comment: When I urlencode() your string, I get `Art%27s+of+Glass%3A+Photos+From+Crystal+Castles%27+Gra`, which seems to be correct.  I'm not sure why you're getting what you're getting.  There might be some odd PHP setting doing on?  However, decoding your "odd" string, it also decodes to the proper string.

Comment: yeah, decoding it on the php side does - the problem is that im decoding it on the JS side, and JS is only doing the one step, meaning reversing the string to the point where the HTML special Char is still in there.

Comment: It's converting (') to `&#039;` (the html special character for apostrophe) and then urlencode() on that which gives `%26%23039%3Bs`. As Quentin mentions, if you just `echo $title` and look at the actual source code, what does it show?  I suspect that the actual string is `Art&#039;s`.  Which will appear as `Art's` in the browser (since it converts it).

Comment: Yessss - you got it. Had to use htmlspecialchars_decode(string, ENT_QUOTES). Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original data probably includes the HTML character reference for `'`

When you `print_r` it, your browser interprets it as HTML and renders a `'`.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable, but then running htmlspecialchars_decode before encoding it should reverse the reference. Oddly it doesn't. I'm starting to think that it is in fact some odd setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this, here it is;

```
<?php
$string = "amir'qureshi";
$postipn3 = urlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES));
//out put will be amir%27qureshi
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what i normally do is:

```
$string = htmlentities($string);
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
```

you can also do:

```
$string = htmlentities(base64_encode($string));
$string = html_entity_decode(base64_decode($string));
```

maybe thats overdoing it but i like it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, when I run this code:

```
<?php
$title = "Art's of Glass: Photos From Crystal Castles' Gra";
$title = urlencode($title);
print_r($title);
?>
```

I get this result:

```
Art%27s+of+Glass%3A+Photos+From+Crystal+Castles%27+Gra
```

Can we see more of your code?  Not sure why you're having that problem from just what you've provided...

Try just using the php snip I used and see if it does the same thing.  If so, like someone else mentioned, it may be a goofy setting in your php configuration somewhere.